# Pronunciation of что phrases

Tags: произношение

Are `потому что` and `то, что` pronounced with the `o` in `что` as `ə`, or as `o`? It seems the former can be both, but which is more standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first phrase, **"потому что"** all three "о" are pronounced as **"shwa" - ə.**  In the second one, **"то, что"** both "о" are pronounced as **"о".**

However in **"потому, что"** the first two "o" are pronounced as **"shwa",** but the last one is stressed and pronounced as **"o".**

Comment: What is the difference between потому что and потому, что?

Comment: @casey, There is no difference in meaning, but depending on the structure of the sentence one may need to use a comma to separate a subordinate clause.  There is a discussion in Russian here: [Запятая в обороте “потому что”](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2803/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE)  As a result of adding a comma *"что"* is pronounced as an independent word with a stressed *"о"*